# How can I prove this relation between derivatives?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, differentiation, calculus

Consider coaixialcable with TEM. Nonstatic fields are being considered, i.e situation obeys $\nabla \times \mathbf {E}=-\frac{\partial \mathbf{B} }{\partial t} $

If I let a eletric field be described as $\textbf{E}=[E^+(z-ct)+E^-(z+ct)]\hat s $

Can someone help me on how to show that : $\frac{\partial E^{\pm} }{\partial z}=\frac{1}{\mp c}\frac{\partial E^{\pm}  }{\partial t}$

Comment: Chain rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule

Answer (score 1):

In just the chain rule.
For example
$$
\partial_x \sin(x-ct)= \cos(x-ct)\\
\partial_t  \sin(x-ct)= -c\cos(x-ct)
$$